# How do Laravel get GET request made by vue.js?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, httprequest

Vue.js HTTP call

```
        methods :{
        login(){
            var data ={
                client_id: 2,
                client_secret: '5YVQ6rsSehoh5BOWsxAU3KxGeqT1tCRGHn5dx1iX',
                grant_type: 'password',
                username : this.email,
                password: this.password
            }
            //send a GET request using Vue-Resource
            this.$http.get("http://localhost/kubikt2/public/api/login", data)
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(response)

                })

        }

    }
```

Laravel

```
Route::get('api/login',function(Illuminate\Http\Request $req){

$arr["echo"]=$req->all();
$arr["test"]="OK!!";

return json_encode($arr);
}
```

As you can see, echo   $req->getContent(); return nothing in Laravel.

[check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/010ls.png)

How do I access the var data sent by Vue.js in Laravel ?

Comment: Have you tried `return $req->getContent();`, or simply `return Response::make("OK!");` instead?

Comment: I've tried to return the echo result in json format. But the response show empy array in Console.

Comment: I try to return a dummy test var, console showed only "test" var is received but not the "echo" var

Comment: Weird.. are you receiving any errors when you do the ajax call?

Comment: I didn't receive any error, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: It works If I add a var "email" after the URL, like this:
this.$http.get("http://localhost/kubikt2/public/api/login?"+email, data)

Laravel Illuminate\Http\Request cannot get var "data" sent from vue.js ?

Comment: Shame on me. Yes, you need a `POST` request to submit data like this without moving them in the URL itself. `GET` requests only evaluate data that is passed via URL (in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$req->all()` is empty because no data is passed!

A `GET` request only evaluates data passed as query-string in the URI. It acts like the `data` parameter is null.

You could send your data as query (like `"localhost/kubikt2/public/api/login?email"+email+"&someMore"+someMore`) or use a `POST` request (which would be the better option here)

Comment: You are welcome! @ethan17 Please don't forget to mark the question as resolved and (if you want to) give an upvote for correct and helpful answers :)